# iOS graphical library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos, ipad

I am in the process of studying iOS and I would like to create a small application, which will put my image on black background and add any text.

Example - http://demotivation.me/images/20130105/d5il8ka359c2.jpg

How is it better to realize it? Which graphical library to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need easy code like this:

```
UIView* backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; // create background view with frame of all screen
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; // set it color

UIImageView* image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]]; // create image view with image you want
image.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 300); // set frame, better to set frame in depending of backgroundView frame, because we've got few types of iOS devices with different displays
[backgroundView addSubview:image]; // place created image to background

UILabel* textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]; // create frame you want with similar way as image
textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
[backgroundView addSubview:textLabel];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView]; // add created backgroundView to your UIViewController's background
```

Answer (score 1):

Use standard iOS SDK functions, manipulating `UIView` and labels.
You don't want anything hard for doing this. Just setting some frames and view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Quartz / Core Graphics for that kind of drawing (for learning purposes). [The Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a good place to start learning more about it.

If you weren't doing this for learning purposes you could easily do this with a view, an image view and a label. Setting that up can all be done in Interface Builder (not very useful for learning though).